# mysqldump --fields-enclosed-by=\" How to escape quote marks in Exec Command in PHP

Tags: php

I have this code that not work: ($output = empty and $result = 1 ... so something wrong);

```
exec("(C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.9\bin\mysqldump.exe -u$username -p$password --tab=$path_to_export --skip-add-drop-table --skip-triggers --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=, $db_name) 2>&1", $output, $result);
```

But if I delete this parameter **--fields-enclosed-by=\"** that working good

From this I deduced that the quotation mark is the problem. Any idea how to escape it correctly?

Comment: Use the `escapeshellarg()` function to escape shell arguments. It says it right there in the name.

Comment: Seem to be the right way that work to export ok but no quote to enclose fields added in exported file. I have tried .escapeshellarg('--fields-enclosed-by=\"'). ... .escapeshellarg('--fields-enclosed-by="'). .escapeshellarg('--fields-enclosed-by=\\"').

Comment: Thanks for the idea, in this way I found **escapeshellcmd()** that works OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `escapeshellarg` to escape shell arguments. Also, you should either escape the backslashes in the pathname, or use forward slashes, because some of them will be interpreted as escape sequences (`\b` is backspace).

```
exec("C:/wamp64/bin/mysql5.7.9/bin/mysqldump.exe -u$username -p" . escapeshellarg($password) . " --tab=$path_to_export --skip-add-drop-table --skip-triggers --fields-enclosed-by=" . escapeshellarg('"') . " --fields-terminated-by=, $db_name 2>&1", $output, $result);
```

Comment: I have tell you also in the above comment escapeshellarg('"') seem to work but not working as espected: espected is "mi_field" and wit escapeshellarg('"') I got mi_field without quotes. but with **escapeshellcmd('"')**  that work as espected: "mi_field"

Comment: Might be an issue with using Windows cmd.com rather than a Unix shell. I don't know if escaping works the same.